# Android: No Launcher activity found! was working before

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have the same problem everyone reports but this began happening suddenly. My app was working as expected, automatically launching the MAIN activity.
But all of the sudden it stopped working and I started seeing the **No Launcher activity found!** message.

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xitrica.android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true" />
    <activity android:name="ElBusetonActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="andoid.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="RouteInfoActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:name="GetDirectionsActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:name="PointProviderList"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Sorry if I'm not posting this snippet correctly. It's the first time I ever post a question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ....it says `<category android:name="andoid.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` **andoid** instead of **android**

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name=".ElBusetonActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

try this, prefix (".") on activity name 
here (.) refer to package path

Comment: I was able to finally fix it. As crazy as it may sound, but what I did is I erased all the code and typed it again. With only 1 change, removed this activity that I was not using.

`<activity android:name="RouteInfoActivity"></activity>`

The Activity class is still there though

Answer (score 0):

Remove
category  android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" 
as it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have the Activity names TestActivity

If you want the TestActivity to be the first to launch when you hit "run", simply add two lines:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

To the position like below in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity
        android:name="TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the dot before the activities in your manifest to declare it. or you can write the package name dot your activity name.
like this.........

```
<activity android:name=".ElBusetonActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

if you not using package name then it decide the default one.