# App Unable to Find Launcher Activity

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have just started to develop a brand new application and I have two Activities set up one which displays the Splash Screen and another the Main one. Here is the manifest file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tried changing android.intent.action also removing the DEFAULT Category line from Main also placing the Splash Activity setup above main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized the .MAIN in action and .LAUNCHER  should be in the same activity , it's working now!

Answer (score 1):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: But I want to show the Splash Activity on Start not the Main activity O_O

Answer (score 0):

check this
[Android: No Launcher activity found! was working before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397476/android-no-launcher-activity-found-was-working-before)

Comment: I referred ti this post and I have the "." prefix set too